# lshw not showing wireless card

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

After a long battle with my Netgear WNDA3100v2, I can now see my adapter with the `lsusb` command, but it is not showing up on the `lshw`.  I did get the Broadcom BCM43xx driver installed successfully, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point.

```
icon@tron:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for icon: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 12
   serial: 00:1b:fc:b2:cd:87
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:44 memory:feafc000-feafffff ioport:c800(size=256) memory:feac0000-feadffff
icon@tron:~$
```

iwconfig

```
# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Also my network manager applet does not seem to want to show up on my screen anywhere.  I followed all the guides I could find on how to restore it, but with no success.  No internet access on the Ubuntu machine either (at least not until the adapter works).  No clue where to go from here, any help would be appreciated greatly.

EDIT:
    ndiswrapper -1

```
icon@tron:~$ ndiswrapper -l
bcmn43xx64 : driver installed
device (0846:9011) present
bcmwlhigh6 : driver installed
device (0846:9011) present
icon@tron:~$
```

LSUSB

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0480:a006 Toshiba America Info. Systems, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn     [Broadcom BCM4323]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 12c9:1001  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 06a3:8021 Saitek PLC Eclipse II Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
icon@tron:~$
```

IWCONFIG

```
icon@tron:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

icon@tron:~$
```

driver uninstall

```
icon@tron:~$ sudo ndiswrapper -e bcmwhigh6
couldn't delete /etc/ndiswrapper/bcmwhigh6: No such file or directory
icon@tron:~$
```

grep

```
icon@tron:~$ dmesg | grep ndis
[  484.366284] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or      required key missing - tainting kernel
[  484.367185] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[  484.668164] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:  NDIS.SYS:'NdisQueueIoWorkItem'
[  484.668173] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeIoWorkItem'
[  484.668179] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSetMiniportAttributes'
[  484.668187] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMResetComplete'
[  484.668192] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMAllocatePort'
[  484.668198] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateIoWorkItem'
[  484.668203] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete'
[  484.668208] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMDeregisterMiniportDriver'
[  484.668214] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferListPool'
[  484.668221] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMNetPnPEvent'
[  484.668229] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:   NDIS.SYS:'NdisMRegisterMiniportDriver'
[  484.668235] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMFreePort'
[  484.668240] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists'
[  484.668247] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMPauseComplete'
[  484.668252] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferListPool'
[  484.668258] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisCancelTimerObject'
[  484.668263] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisOpenConfigurationEx'
[  484.668268] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisSetTimerObject'
[  484.668274] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeTimerObject'
[  484.668280] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateTimerObject'
[  484.668286] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateStatusEx'
[  484.668291] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferList'
[  484.668303] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:   NDIS.SYS:'NdisMGetBusData'
[  484.668308] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisGetSystemUpTimeEx'
[  484.668314] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferAndNetBufferList'
[  484.668319] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMdl'
[  484.668325] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeMdl'
[  484.668334] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMOidRequestComplete'
[  484.668339] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMemoryWithTagPriority'
[  484.668350] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBind'
[  484.668355] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBindClass'
[  484.668359] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbindClass'
[  484.668364] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbind'
[  484.668366] ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'bcmwlhigh6'
[  484.668873] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver bcmwlhigh6; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
[  484.668931] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
[  951.800411] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ndiswrapper
[  951.811487] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[  952.063997] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisQueueIoWorkItem'
[  952.064041] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeIoWorkItem'
[  952.064049] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSetMiniportAttributes'
[  952.064058] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMResetComplete'
[  952.064064] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMAllocatePort'
[  952.064069] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateIoWorkItem'
[  952.064075] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete'
[  952.064080] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMDeregisterMiniportDriver'
[  952.064085] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferListPool'
[  952.064093] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMNetPnPEvent'
[  952.064102] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMRegisterMiniportDriver'
[  952.064107] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMFreePort'
[  952.064114] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists'
[  952.064121] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:   NDIS.SYS:'NdisMPauseComplete'
[  952.064126] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferListPool'
[  952.064131] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisCancelTimerObject'
[  952.064137] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisOpenConfigurationEx'
[  952.064142] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisSetTimerObject'
[  952.064147] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeTimerObject'
[  952.064154] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateTimerObject'
[  952.064160] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateStatusEx'
[  952.064165] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferList'
[  952.064177] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMGetBusData'
[  952.064183] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisGetSystemUpTimeEx'
[  952.064188] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferAndNetBufferList'
[  952.064193] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMdl'
[  952.064199] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeMdl'
[  952.064208] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:   NDIS.SYS:'NdisMOidRequestComplete'
[  952.064213] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMemoryWithTagPriority'
[  952.064225] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBind'
[  952.064229] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBindClass'
[  952.064233] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbindClass'
[  952.064238] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbind'
[  952.064240] ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'bcmwlhigh6'
[  952.064728] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver bcmwlhigh6; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
[  952.064778] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
icon@tron:~$
```

Comment: Please add: `ndiswrapper -l`, `lsusb` and also: `iwconfig`. Thanks.

Comment: edited original post to include

Comment: `ndiswrapper -l` the l is a lower case L not a 1, must be something related to the code tags that make it look like a 1

Comment: i stared at it for a bit wondering.. one sec ill relog and update..

Comment: ok fixed it before too many people saw that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need both bcmwlhigh6 and bcmn43xx64. I believe the latter is correct, so let's remove the former.

```
sudo ndiswrapper -e bcmwlhigh6
sudo modprobe -r ndiswrapper && sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Any improvement? If not, post:

```
dmesg | grep ndis
```

I will edit my answer to refine a solution once we know more details from you.

Comment: the driver does not want to work with me on this

Comment: As it turns out, I apparently can't read... Once I fixed the spelling error in the drive name, it uninstalled and the adapter immediately picked up wireless signals.  Ty so much for the help.  Couldn't have done it without you

Comment: Glad it's working and sorry for the misstep. I've edited the answer for the benefit of the searchers.

Comment: Good to have you back!  ;-)